# SVG image as pattern - full width - keep ratio

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to create this type of separator:

### [image: Separator: The guy welding]

But i cannot make it work, the image is never fully stretched or deforms or is a pattern...

The SVG shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="bigTriangleColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
     y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1024 1379.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1024 1379.4;" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon points="0,1 0,341 0,1037.4 0,1377.4 1024,1037.4 1024,341 "/>
</svg>
```

A SVG pattern (a tryout):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1024 1379.4" version="1.1" width="100%" height="200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="img4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
          <image xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507181179506-598491b53db4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=299b6fae13eb39086f5bb28029c61760&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1778&q=80" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
    <polygon points="0,1 0,341 0,1037.4 0,1377.4 1024,1037.4 1024,341" fill="url(#img4)"/>
    </svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Bucky208/b3jhsem4/

This is with clippath (Not supported on edge and IE?!) and it also stretches on full witdh:

```
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
       y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1024 1381.5" width="100%" height="800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1024 1381.5;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
    </style>
    <g>
      <defs>
        <polygon id="SVGID_1_" points="0,572.1 0,1381.3 1024,1040.5 1024,337.6 0,0    "/>
      </defs>
      <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
      </clipPath>
      <g class="st0">
        <defs>
          <rect id="SVGID_3_" x="-3.1" y="0" width="1030" height="1381.3"/>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
          <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
        </clipPath>
        <g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);">

            <image style="overflow:visible;" width="331" height="444" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507160634214-89e0baae2457?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=9df168bddae101e185e697926806634f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80"  transform="matrix(3.1119 0 0 3.1111 -3.0528 -2.604167e-04)">
          </image>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Bucky208/3xvh8kn1/1/

**The goal:**

- 100% width
- The image does not deform
- The width of the shape itself
  **may** deform (fixed height)

Kind regards

Comment: What you most likely want is `preserveAspectRatio="none"` in your image

Comment: No. OP wanted to keep the correct aspect ratio, not stretch the image.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, all you have to do is set the appropriate `preserveAspectRatio` on your image. In this case, one with the keyword `slice`.  SVG's `slice` is equivalent to the value `cover` for the `background-size` CSS property in HTML.

In the example, below, I do the following:

1. Leave the pattern using the default `patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and set `width` and `height` to `"1"` so that our pattern covers the whole object.
2. Set `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and set the image `width` and `height` to `"1"` so that the image covers the whole shape.
3. Set the image to us `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` so that the image is scaled up to cover the whole object bounding box.

Also, I changed the image to one that makes it more easy to tell that it is keeping its aspect ratio.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1024 1379.4" version="1.1" width="100%" height="200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img4" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <image x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
             xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520658402001-b5960f9a6059?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5670796b33630d3eff4b287840632a59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="0,1 0,341 0,1037.4 0,1377.4 1024,1037.4 1024,341" fill="url(#img4)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou, how can i make the SVG the full width of the page, stretch the svg and the image inside should be the item with the cover equivalent. The SVG is a bit like a mask.

I have this now:
https://jsfiddle.net/7dy3q6wn/2/

But its not working on IE :/

Comment: You don't need any Javascript. Just set your `<div>` to 100% width.  SVGs default to 100% width as well, and will automatically be the appropriate height as determined by the `viewBox` aspect ratio. https://jsfiddle.net/7dy3q6wn/7/